# How to protect my php page to sql injection

Tags: php, .htaccess

this is my http://localhost/abc/read_story.php?story_id=3' page and i want to protect from sql injection.  How is possible?

I want display above url like this http://localhost/abc/read_story/3.

I also try using .htaccess but not worked.
my .htaccess code is follow:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^read_story/([0-9a-zA-Z]+).html http://localhost/abc/read_story.php?story_id=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: there's nothing sql related there

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Comment: SQL injection has nothing to do with .htaccess  
Take care of your SQL queries and use `prepared statement` for that.

Answer (score 0):

The rewrite rule should be

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^read_story/([0-9]+)$ read_story.php?story_id=$1 [NC,L]
```

Use prepared statements against SQL injection attacks.